# Enabling "fast user switching" for XP domain PC for when a session is locked

Tags: windows-xp, lock, fast-user-switching

We have a shared PC which is often left unattended for long enough for it to go to the lock screen.

Other users who need to use it are confronted with the lock screen (which does not have the "switch user" option) and cannot do any work.

How can I make it possible for other users to log in as themselves despite the initial user's session being locked? (This is a domain XP workstation and the "switch user" option is not available at the lock screen.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast User Switching simply is not available on Windows XP computers that are joined to a domain.  Windows Vista and 7 support Fast User Switching on domain computers. (I'm guessing Windows 8 does also, but cannot verify.)

See also:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279765

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/21/55799.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the concise answer and links. Saved me looking around trying to enable something that just isn't possible in XP. Thanks!